# Shared system partition for multiple linux system

Tags: boot, partition, dual-boot

Is it okay to share some partitions for multiple native linux system? For example, if I want to install Ubuntu, Debian and Arch in one harddisk, and I create lvm partition scheme like this:

```
NAME                TYPE  MOUNTPOINT  DESC
sda
  sda1              part  
    vg-shared_boot  lvm   /boot
    vg-shared_home  lvm   /home
    vg-shared_swap  lvm   [SWAP]
    vg-ubuntu_root  lvm   /           # when boot on Ubuntu
    vg-debian_root  lvm   /           # when boot on Debian
    vg-arch_root    lvm   /           # when boot on Arch
```

Is this will work?

Comment: Some distributions keep in /boot the kernels so it is wise to make one for each distribution. And also is good to put /boot outside of lvm

Comment: Its pretty common to share `/home` and `swap` mount points "cross-distro". Some points you will have to take care is: 1 - Create the user across all distros using the SAME UID and main GID. 2 - Take a particular care with ownership. Some distrbutions use the `users` as your main group while others, use a group with the same name of the user created.

Comment: If you're sharing filesystems and/or swap, don't use hibernate (suspend to disk) unless you can guarantee that you won't use the "other" distribution while one is in this state.